How do I learn to write well?
I don't know if this is the place for this, but whatever. I am a first-year college student who's highly invested in self-education and gaining knowledge. I always strive to know more. I read a lot and enjoy learning and thinking more than anything else. I have no trouble understanding most of what I read and study, especially if it's verbally based; think philosophy or social science. That being said, I've noticed that I'm not living up to my potential in certain areas.
For example, I'm poor at clear, organized writing. I'm often made aware, directly or implicitly, that I'm verbose and scattered in my output. Recently, I went to my campus's writing lab thing to get some help with an essay, and the tutor couldn't even get through my paper. She said that my paragraphs didn't seem well connected and that my thesis was vague and unfitting. There were some other things she said that seemed to reflect misunderstanding, but it's my responsibility to write something that makes sense.
Given that I value the "life of the mind", it's probably good that people at least know what I mean when I speak or write. I tried getting advice from AI, but it usually just spits back platitudes. "Focus on conciseness" and what-not. No, really? What I'd like to know is how. Any help is appreciated and I'm open to answer questions.

Write for their brain, not yours

it's my responsibility to write something that makes sense.

Consider how human's speak when we train a dog: simple commands, 1 or 2 words maximum – and always the same consistent words, and almost always said as a positive or an action they want the dog to perform.
Now consider how we instruct a small child (younger than 6 years old). We speak in complete sentences, but also careful not to introduce stray ideas or abstract concepts. They are easily distracted, they don't understand sarcasm or nuance, and they aren't able to redirect themselves back on track after they lose focus.
Last example, think about the average stranger who has asked for directions. They want information not for the pleasure of talking but because they are lost. They will need to recall the steps in order. Any extra descriptions or anecdotes will be mind-clutter that will make remembering difficult.
Reduce 'noise' to boost the signal
As the speaker in these situations, we have to respect that too much information works against the goal. It's not 'dumbing down' in fact the opposite, we hope the listener is smart. But we have to respect the other person is a receiver at the other end of a squishy uncertain biological process that must function in their brain, not ours.
A lot of the purposeful signal will be lost to brain-noise just within their biological process. You must communicate a clear signal, and filter out your own brain-noise. It is unreasonable to expect the reader to filter both their noise and your noise successfully. Don't make it harder for them.

Understand the goal for your communication, what are they suppose to learn?
Remove your 'personality' from academic writing, it's confusing.
Build from zero, assume they are lost and just want directions (direct, and point-to-point).
Organize the paper as 'stepping stones': sub-concepts that are built upon, do not skip steps or jump around in context.
Introduce, explain, and summarize each sub-concept individually and compartmentally: structural patterns that alert the reader the focus is moving to the next sub-topic.
Orient the reader so they understand where you are headed. They will be more receptive to your information when they understand the end goal.
Edit. Reduce word count. Simplify. Be direct.


Here’s one simple technique that can be very effective in helping both (1) recognize what information in a text is unnecessary and can/should be deleted, and (2) sequence what remains to improve clarity. It’s called question factoring.
The idea is to proceed through a text sentence by sentence and “on a separate piece of paper” compile a list of the questions they answer. It’s a bit like the TV game show Jeopardy!. You are replacing each sentence by the (or more often a) question to which it is the answer. As an example, I‘ll apply question factoring to this very paragraph:

What is the main idea behind question factoring?
Is there anything I’m familiar with to which it can be compared?
What actually goes on?
Could you illustrate what it looks like in practice?

The reason it’s useful is that from the sequence of questions it’s usually much easier to recognize the flow of ideas than from the original text. You can imagine the sequence of questions as a journalist’s interview. You can delete questions that are out of place, off topic, superfluous, or the like. You can also add any questions that are missing. And you can rearrange them for a more natural and smooth flow.
Once you have improved the list of questions, you simply replace each improved question with a sentence that answers it.
I’ve described the technique as applicable to sentences, but it can be applied also at higher levels too (for instance, What is the question that this paragraph answers?)

You are in school, and you are going to be writing a lot of papers. It is great that you are taking this seriously and want to improve. Whatever approach you take, you will want to make sure that you are producing good writing and that you can do it efficiently.
Your stated goal is "clear, organized writing." One approach is to start the process with a focus on clearly deciding what you want to say (not how you want to say it yet!), and how you want to organize it. After you have defined and refined your plan, then you start writing.
The basic idea is to start with an outline. For an essay, start with one bullet point per paragraph, with each bullet point just being a short phrase or question (that the paragraph will answer). Keep working at this level until you feel like the scope and flow is appropriate and makes sense. At this level, it is easy to keep the whole essay in mind at the same time.
Then, start breaking down each of the paragraph bullets into a couple to a few sub-bullets. Here, you are planning out what points you want to make to address the paragraph topic. Keep editing the paragraph's outline until you are happy with the plan. Rework and reorganize the paragraphs if necessary.
Now you can start writing your first draft. Work one paragraph at a time, turning each item in the paragraph's outline into one to a few sentences. Tweak the paragraph transitions if necessary to aid with the flow of thoughts.
You may see parallels between this approach and that suggested by Paul in his answer. In Paul's approach, you write a draft first, then extract an outline from what you wrote (to aid you in the editing process). In my approach, you go straight to the outline and defer writing until you have everything organized. Both approaches explicitly consider "why" each sentence is there (what point it is trying to make). This helps you consider if a given point is really worth making.
Starting with an outline works well for me. One aspect in particular that I find helpful is a clear separation and focus on either planning/organizing vs. writing the the sentence or two for one bullet point. These are very different activities that utilize different parts of the brain.
When I try to simultaneously plan, organize, and write, I find it hard to do any of those tasks well. Invariably, I end up deleting more than half my words during my first editing pass.
By planning first, by the time I am writing, I only have to focus on how to express one simple idea clearly and concisely. My first draft invariably comes out ok and required significantly less editing. With explicit planning, I find it faster to get my first draft, and faster to get from there to my final draft.

Our thinking is complex and multidimensional in its structure and associative in its connections. Academic writing, on the other hand, is linear and expected to be constructed logically. Translating the one into the other takes some practice.
What you can do is what all writers do to get better:

Read a lot of what you want to write to achieve an intuitive understanding of the genre.
Do a writing exercise (for uni or privately).
While you write, try and remember that your readers do not know what you want to say. Attempt to explain your thoughts as precisely and clearly as possible. Use simple language and syntax.
When you are done, put your writing away for a while (ideally, until you have forgotten what you wrote).
Reread the whole text — quickly! — making only quick notes (e.g. a circle around the passage) to remind you where you need to redact something. Do not start correcting your mistakes before you have read the whole text.
Revise the parts that seem confusing or incomprehensible to you.
Submit your essay or whatever it is or find some beta readers.
Read the feedback you get. Don't argue with your beta readers.
Revise your text again (even if it is not expected) for practice and correct what your readers have criticised.
Put that text away and write the next text.
Keep at it until you get the feedback you want.

